# .htaccess rewrite with GET variables

Tags: php, .htaccess

am trying to create a url like this using htaccess...
[www.example.com/user/david](http://www.example.com/user/david)

what i have now is this [www.example.com/user?username=david](http://www.example.com/user?username=david)

It works well when i do something like

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.*/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)|([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+))$ ./user.php?username=$1 [L]
```

But i am wrong at my php code.

```
if(isset($_GET["username"]))
{
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM campus_users WHERE campus_name = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $campus_name );
    $campus_name = trim($_GET["username"]);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();

    if ($result->num_rows == 1) {
        $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        //displaying users rows
    } else {
        header("location: blank-page");
      exit();
    }
} else {
  header("location: home.php");
  exit();
}
```

But when i enter the url like this [www.example.com/user?username=david](http://www.example.com/user?username=david) it works well...

The problem is i want a smart looking url which isnt working due to my php i guess.

Please help me.
**Thanks in advance.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your URL with query string is working fine then it most probably it means your `.htaccess` rules are not working, usually we give user friendly URLs to users in your case it should be `www.example.com/user/david` and internally it should route to `www.example.com/user.php?username=david`. Please try following Rules in your `.htaccess` file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/user/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^.*$ /user.php?username=%1 [QSA,NC,NE,L]
```

***NOTE:*** if possible and you are not on prod systems then you could try to restart your Apache service too, though it's not necessary but sometimes it may be required. Also use user friendly URL as mentioned above in browser make sure you clear the browser cache before hitting it.

Comment: Thanks so much. i really appreciate your effort.

Comment: The first .htaccess you posted wont load the page at all. it show me error... object not found

Comment: @Everythinggood, these rules are very well worked for me when I tested them in local. Could you please do let me know any errors you are getting?

Comment: @Everythinggood, so your php file name is user.php which you want to redirect to, am I right here?

Comment: The second gives me this long url http://localhost/campus/?username=&username=&username=&username=&username=&username=&username=&username=&username=&username=&username=&username=&username=&username=&username=&username=&username=&username=&username=user/username

Comment: @Everythinggood, ok I have edited my solution, could you please check it now and let me know how it goes?